# Adding Colors to a Color array

Tags: java, arrays, colors

I am writing a program where I take an image determine the average red channel, green channel and blue channel present in that image. I take these averages and pass them as parameters to a new color. I then want to add this color to an array. I repeat this process 24 times. The problem I face is that when I get a new color and add it to the array the previous colors get erased. I want to preserve the existing colors in the array and add to the one that hasn't been filled yet. Here is what I have tried.

```
System.out.println("R: "+ rAvg);
System.out.println("G: "+ gAvg);
System.out.println("B: "+ bAvg);


Color newColor = new Color(rAvg, gAvg, bAvg);
Color[] ColorArr = new Color[24];

for(int i = 0; i < ColorArr.length; i++){
     ColorArr[i] = newColor;
        }

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ColorArr));
```

Here is the output after one color is added to the array

```
 R: 206
 G: 0
 B: 0
 [java.awt.Color[r=206,g=0,b=0],java.awt.Color[r=206,g=0,b=0]
```

Here is the array after I add a new color.

```
R: 211
G: 178
B: 230
[java.awt.Color[r=211,g=178,b=230], java.awt.Color[r=211,g=178,b=230]
```

The last color gets overwritten and replaced with the new color instead of going in the next index and preserving the last. How can I fix this so I preserve the entered colors in the array and place the new color the index after the previous?

Comment: Your `for-loop` replaces every element in the array with the new `Color`.  You'll have to store a counter somewhere in your program and increment it for each of the 24 iterations.

Comment: Your array contains 24 elements, how come it is printing only 2 elements? I did not understand

Comment: I didn't show the whole thing because it is really long but it is a repeat of what is there 24 times. @javaguy

Comment: Something like this @JacobG.  

`int counter = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < ColorArr.length; i++){
      
       ColorArr[counter] = newColor;
       counter++;
     }
     `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restructure your code to something like this:

```
private Color[] colorArray = new Color[24];
private int currentIndex = 0;

public void addColorToArray(int red, int green, int blue) {
  colorArray[currentIndex++] = new Color(red, green, blue);
}

public void myMethodThatDoThis24Times() {
   addColorToArray(getRedAverage(), getGreenAverage(), getBlueAverage());
   addColorToArray(getRedAverage(), getGreenAverage(), getBlueAverage());
   ...
}
```

Comment: Your logic looks better than mine. I got to learn few things from you. Thanks and a upvote :)

Comment: I am looking at this just in case you are wondering, I am working making it work with my code.

Comment: You can post your complete code on say, http://ideone.com/ and paste the  link to it here.

Comment: Here is the whole method. @DevendraLattu still trying to make it work with his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic looks correct. The only thing which you need to take care is creating a new instance of color object every time.

```
//ColorArr[i] = newColor;                    // Instead of this
ColorArr[i] = new Color(rAvg, gAvg, bAvg);   // Do this for each element in array
```

You were initially doing `Color newColor = new Color(rAvg, gAvg, bAvg);` and assign the same `newColor` instance to all the elements in the `ColorArr`.

Thus, a single change in the `newColor` instance was reflecting the change in all its referenced elements in the array.

As @user alayor, rightly suggested to create new instances of Color(rAvg, gAvg, bAvg) with different RGB values.

Comment: This replaces the whole array, the previous entries are overwritten.

Comment: @cuber, I hope my solution helped you. I would appreciate if you can upvote my code :) Thanks

Comment: it did help out too I started to see where my flaw was. @Devendra Lattu